# Changing login popup page to the home page without popup

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, jhipster

Hello I am using Jhipster 4 using Angular 2 .
I want change the login page to a simple page html published on the home page not in popup .
I didn't find away to resolve this issue please someone can help me ?
Tahnks

Answer (score 0):

you can try to create a new login component and html next add this to service and route. In component you can add same functionality of login and show in page not on popUp, or change the custom login component and modify tro show this in popUp